# (Empty) Protocol conforming test

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

Here something which puzzles me a little bit.

I have defined this empty protocol for testing purposes:

```
protocol Doable {
}
```

The protocol being empty I expect any possible type conform to it.

But when I use this code to perform a simple protocol conforming test, using two ways.

```
if let _ = MyType.self as? Doable {
    print("Doable match OK!!")
} else {
    print("That doesn't match!!")
}

if MyType.self is Doable.Type {
    print("Doable match OK!!")
} else {
    print("That doesn't match!!")
}
```

I always get as a result that: *IT DOES NOT MATCH*.

Is that what is supposed to happen?

Or is my test or expectation wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if a type meets the requirements of a protocol, its conformance has to be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2):

A Swift type is conforming to a protocol only if it explicitly implements it.

For adding a protocol conformance to - for example - a standard type (like String), you can :

```
extension String: Doable {}
let aString = ""
if aString is Doable {
 print("it works")
}
```

See more details on how this works in the [Apple documentation on protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

You can also have a look at *conditional conformance*, a Swift 4 feature which can help for your need.
[Conditional conformance](https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/)

**Note**:

In real-life code this test is useless because Swift compiler knows in that case that *String* ***is*** *Doable*

Comment: That seems very interesting, I'll try to make use of it.